# How to notify the UI that a change has taken place in one or several of a List's members

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, list, binding

I have the following problem:

I am adding an element to a favorites list (`List<Item>`) through a `ContextMenu`. Each `Item` has a derived property `IsFavorite` that changes depending on the favorites list - like so:

```
public bool IsFavorite
{
    get { return ItemController.FavoriteList.Contains( this ); }
}
```

When I add something (or delete it) from the `ContextMenu`, the `ContextMenu` must be immediately updated.

Now, I know this is possible through using an ObservableCollection, but due to a few factors out of my control, I must make due with `List` objects. Now, is there any way I can get this to refresh?

Comment: If you rebind it might refresh.  Why can you not change to ObservableCollection?  ObservableCollection implements List so it should not break anything.

Comment: I think even with an ObservableCollection there would be no notification about a change of the `IsFavorite` property, unless you manually add [CollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.collectionchanged.aspx) handlers and fire a PropertyChanged event for `IsFavorite`.

Comment: Figured out a way to get around it. Not very pretty, that's for sure, but when the Item is added to the Favorite list, I was able to fire the PropertyChanged of that object directly.

Comment: Well, you can't really know for a fact that your `IsFavorite` changes since you don't define where is it changed (ie in a `set` ). Usually UI gets notified when a `PropertyChanged` event is fired. However here, you won't set this property and will never fier any `PropertyChanged`, so you'll probably have to add a `CollectionChanged` handler manually on `FavoriteList` which fires `PropertyChanged` when this changed. Or maybe going through a multi-bound `DataTrigger` + a converter returning true if IsFavorite but... this would be ugly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void DeleteFromFavorites(Item item)
{
    Item itemInMainList = MainList.First(item);
    itemInMainList.Refresh();
}
```

Item.cs:

```
public bool IsFavorite
{
    get { return ItemController.FavoriteList.Contains( this ); }
}

public void Refresh()
{
    NotifyPropertyChanged("IsFavorite");
}
```